# Removing frame and replacing with new one in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to replace a frame with a new one. The first function works fine and the frame gets replaced, but when I try and revert back, on the second function, the debug shows "blah" properly, but besides that, nothing happens.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionPageViewer_triggered()
{
    ui->gridLayout->removeWidget(sc_e->ui->widget);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(sc_p->ui->widget);
}

void MainWindow::on_actionEditor_triggered()
{
    qDebug()<< "blah";
    ui->gridLayout->removeWidget(sc_p->ui->widget);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(sc_e->ui->widget);
}
```

Comment: try ui->gridLayout->update()

Comment: It didn't change anything...

Comment: why these are different callbacks? on_actionPageViewer and on_actionEditor

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. On each action/click, a different window replaces the current one in gridLayout.

Comment: yes, true, apologies. On second call widget is not removed?

Comment: Yes, nothing happens on second call, except for the debug showing "blah".

Comment: is sc_p->ui->widget or sc_e->ui->widget in nested layout?

Comment: I think so, they are nested in a layout. I just figured out why, however, `removeWidget()` deletes the widget, I think, so I can't add it again. I'll add the solution.

Comment: No it does not delete the widget. See Qt documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ui->gridLayout->removeWidget(QWidget*)` deletes the widget, so it cannot be added anymore. Instead of removing it, I can add all of the widgets upon initialization and then just use `setVisible()` to make it show up or to hide it.

So now the code looks like this:

In the initialization:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(sc_e->ui->widget);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(sc_p->ui->widget);
    sc_p->ui->widget->setVisible(false);
}
```

Then:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionPageViewer_triggered()
{

    ui->gridLayout->update();
    sc_e->ui->widget->setVisible(false);
    sc_p->ui->widget->setVisible(true);

}

void MainWindow::on_actionEditor_triggered()
{

    qDebug()<< "blah";
    sc_p->ui->widget->setVisible(false);
    sc_e->ui->widget->setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: QLayout::removeWidget documentation says:
"Removes the widget widget from the layout. After this call, it is the caller's responsibility to give the widget a reasonable geometry or to put the widget back into a layout." So it is *not* deleted.

Comment: I read that, but it didn't work. It acts like it's deleted. Also, somewhere else I found that it might be deleted, so a bit confusing. I'll try show() sometime and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to show() the widgets after adding them to the layout?